# Customize JasperReport-Server Report that made using Ad Hoc View

Tags: jasperserver

I'm supposed to customize the view of Report that made using Ad Hoc View of JasperReport-Server, is there any way to achieve this?. Tried reading all the docs provided, but no luck.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How would you like to customize it?

Comment: Whenever the user print the report to pdf, all input parameter is displayed on the pdf. It's really easy when the report is made using iReport, but I have no clue how to do this when the report made using ad-hoc view.